# Error while trying to Import CSV to MongoDB using PySpark

Tags: mongodb, csv, pyspark

I am trying to upload / import CSV file in MongoDB in my local and this is what I am trying

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("MongoDB") \
    .setMaster("local[*]") \
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/Scrub_Data.RPT_AR") \
    .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/Scrub_Data.RPT_AR")

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.csv("mypathtocsvfile", header=True, inferSchema=True)

df.write \
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/Scrub_Data.RPT_AR") \
    .save()
```

The above code is throwing **Py4JJavaError** An error occurred while calling o39.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that the **Spark connector for MongoDB** is not available on your system. You need to make sure that you have the required packages installed for Spark to communicate with MongoDB.